# Marker drawing order from pointToLayer Function in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I implemented a GeoJson File into my map. It consists of waypoints extracted from a gpx file and is drawn based on the "sym" attribute.

```
    var Wegpunkte = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("tour.geojson",{
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var smallIcon = L.icon({

                      iconAnchor: [14, 14],
                      popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
                      iconUrl: 'icons/' + feature.properties.sym + '.png'
   });

   return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
```

This method works pretty well. The only problem I have now, is that I not sure how to set up the drawing order of the different categories. In the screenshot for example, I'd like to bring the parking lot sign to the front.

[image: Screenshot of Markers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet controls ordering of layers with so called map panes, which are DOM elements, each having it's own `zIndex`. There are several default map panes where different layers go by default (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-pane).

All markers go to `markerPane` which has `zIndex` value of 600. Since all markers go to one pane, marker add later cover those added before. If you want to control vertical order of markers, you can use create your own map panes with map `.createPane` method and assign them different `zIndex` values with `mapPane.style.zIndex = myZindex` statement.

When creating marker, it can be then put on desired map pane with the `pane` option.

In your case code could then look something like this (since I don't know real feature properties, I assumed `'red'` and `'parking'`):

```
map.createPane('markersParking');
map.getPane('markersParking').style.zIndex = 630;
map.createPane('markersRed');
map.getPane('markersRed').style.zIndex = 625;

var Wegpunkte = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("tour.geojson", {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var smallIcon = L.icon({
      iconAnchor: [14, 14],
      popupAnchor:  [1, -24],
      iconUrl: 'icons/' + feature.properties.sym + '.png'
    });
    var pane;
    if (feature.properties.sym == 'red')
      pane = 'markersRed';
    else if (feature.properties.sym == 'parking')
      pane = 'markersParking';
    else {
      pane = 'markerPane';
    }
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon, pane: pane});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks TomazicM, making custom map panes was my first thought as well. The problem I have with this method is, that all the markers retruned from the GeoJSON go into one map pane and I can't fix the drawing order between the different markers created from my GeoJSON. Fo example: My GeoJSON point to Layer function creates a parking lot and a red circle. Both are assigned to the same map pane using L.marker(latlng{pane:topMarkers}). Is there any chance I can organize the drawing order without relabeling the entire attribute table of the GeoJSON?

Comment: But you obviously have some property to differentiate between parking lot and red circle marker. Just create two map panes, one with 625 and the other with 630 zIndex value and assign markers to the corresponding pane, depending on property.

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank's a lot. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: While it looks exactly like I I intented it to be now, I struggle with the popups for the Markers which are in the custom panes. While all points in the regular markerPane have their popup available on click,it fails to open the popups on click of the markersRed and markersParking pane. When I move  them to the regular markerPane, the popups work again. Any suggestion?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to say what goes wrong. Post a new question with the relevant code included.